# I am a beginner to Android App Dev: I am getting a force close all the time

Tags: java, android

I have recently just started learning how to develop android applications. I am am fairly proficient in Java, but I am still trying to get the hang of Android and xml stuffs.

So, thanks for the help in advance:D!

Right now, I am just trying to create an application that has an EditText widget and a button. Currently, all my code does is create an OnClickListener for the button, and define the OnClick method. I have no idea why it is force closing. I have experimented with a few small programs before(mainly experimenting with buttons), and I have also had this problem a few times, so I don't think it is unique to this code.

Here is the code:

```
public class AdditionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(AdditionActivity.this, "Welcome to Addition Helper!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final EditText answerBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerBox);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView problem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.problem);
//        
        //problem.setText("5+4");

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(AdditionActivity.this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                String temp = problem.getText().subSequence(0, 1).toString();
                int first = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                temp = problem.getText().subSequence(2,3).toString();
                int second = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                int answer = first + second;
                if(Integer.parseInt(answerBox.getText().toString()) == answer) 
                    Toast.makeText(AdditionActivity.this, "Correct!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(AdditionActivity.this, "WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So if anyone knows why a beginner might be getting frequent force closes or if I am doing something wrong with my code, that would be GREAT! In my layout xml file, all I have are the EditText widget, the TextView widget, and the button.

Thanks again for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The output of logcat will tell you what's causing the force close. Click on DDMS in eclipse, then look for the logcat tab.

Comment: When does it force close? Before you can see the UI, or when you click the button, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your scenario is type in 1 + 1 in EditText, press button and get result shown in TextView. hence,

This is wrong: EditText answerBox and TextView problem
This is correct: EditText problem and TextView answerBox

force close is mostly due to NullPointerException or ArrayIndexOutofBoundException from this line:

```
String temp = problem.getText().subSequence(0, 1).toString();
```

Comment: No, you are supposed to get a random addition question, and then you put in the answer, it it will tell you if the number that you put in is correct.
Could you elaborate about the NullPointerException or ArrayIndexOutofBoundException?

THANKS

Comment: How do you populate the problem textview initially, Via xml or program? I see you comment out problem.setText("5+4"); if textview has nothing, then problem.getText() return empty string, you get ArrayIndexOutofBoubdException when subsquence(0,1) a empty string.

Comment: In the resources I created a string and I put that string in the problem TextView. After the user has entered an answer, I then change the text in the TextView. So, there shouldn't be a error right?

Comment: As someone has already suggested, if you use Eclipse, logcat can tell everything, click Window -> Open Prespective -> DDMS.